# How to parse a nested unpredictable parameterised Json without creating any POJO?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, web

Receiving JSON input from server whose parameter name may change with time. output format which also will be a json is fixed. But input json may change as it comes from different publishers. Client want an externaal mapping file(json format also) which they will only modify if input json property name needs to be modified or extra parameter is needed. It's spring boot project. Input Json will be nested and may not be nested depending on the publishers.
[Input JSON-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RTZm.jpg)

[respective Output JSON-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPIZO.jpg)

Comment: Please share some json data :)

Comment: input and output json samples are added as image.

Comment: @SouvikAdhikary Please don't use images to share input and output. Please add it to your question as code snippet so that it would be easy for people here to copy paste and save their time to replicate what is expected.

Comment: @NishantSaini tried but getting restricted as it shows formatting error

Answer (score 0):

Without creating POJO, it is possible. You would need to get json property values by property name. You may like to explore com.google.gson.JsonParser. It takes Json String and parses it. 
    JsonParser myParser = new JsonParser();
    JsonElement elems = myParser.parse(jsonString);

Comment: exactly. But how do i get JSON property names? incoming json is unpredictable and may contain any property names which may differ for different publishers. Tried this using HashMap but things are really getting complex if i use Map.

Comment: Please take a look at this, see if this can be helpful. https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java/blob/master/JSONObject.java

Comment: This has a method by name getNames which returns you an array of field names of the JSONObject.

Comment: JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        String[] keys = JSONObject.getNames(object);
        for (String key : keys)
        {
            Object value = object.get(key);
            System.out.println(key + " = " + value.toString());
        }

Comment: JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonString);
I have raw .json input
How to convert input json file into string?

Comment: try {
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream("/<yourfilePath>/some.json");
            BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line = buf.readLine();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while (line != null) {
                sb.append(line).append("\n");
                line = buf.readLine();
            }
            jsonString = sb.toString();




        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

Comment: You can convert file content into a string.

Comment: @RakeshRoy there is no need to use File as the data is coming from api ,server

Comment: @JaiDixit In the line above, the question was how to convert a file into a String. The comment was in that context.